# Find an open set which has finite length and is super set of rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

We define the length of the open set as the difference between the ends.

$l[(a,b)]=b-a$ and

$l[(a,b)\cup(c,d)]\leq l[(a,b)]+l[(c,d)]$

We have to find one open set $U$ such that $l(U)<\infty$ and $Q\subset U$

Comment: The only such $U$ is $\Bbb R$ since the quotient numbers can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: But the problem with $\mathbb{R}$ is that its length is not finite

Comment: If you define open sets as intervals here, the question does not have an answer.

Comment: No such set exists. Are you sure this is what you're being asked to do?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. That's why I was confused.

Comment: There exists an open set $U$ such that $\mathbb Q \subset U$ and Lebesgue measure of $U$ (which is the sum of the lengths of all the intervals which form a disjoint collection with union $U$) is finite. I think this is what was intended here.

Comment: I remember that in class $\mathbb{Q}$ was defined as $\mathbb{Q} =\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ and then $U = \cup{(x_n-1/2^n,x_n+1/2^n)}$. Now the length is less than 2. I understand that length will be less than 2 but are we allowed to define these sets like this.

Comment: @AvanishSingh After you well-order the rationals, then that is a perfectly fine.  However, we need to either assume $l$ is _countably_ subadditive (or prove it if $l$ is a given set function).  The properties you gave in the question aren't sufficient to bound $l(U)$ for your $U.$

Comment: There was one more property given that $l[(a,b)\cup (c,d)]= l[(a,b)]+l[(c,d)]$ if $(a,b)\cap (c,d)=\phi$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably running into problems because of *too much detail*. In the usual (AFAIK) approach, the only relevant property of $\mathbb{Q}$ is that it is countable; remembering how $\mathbb{Q}$ is topologically embedded into $\mathbb{R}$ is an irrelevant detail that only gets in the way of understanding.

The usual method proves:

*Theorem:* Let $S$ be a countably infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then there is an open set of finite length containing $S$.

In fact, you can impose an upper bound; for any $\epsilon > 0$ you can find a set of length less than $\epsilon$.

The construction is basically figure:

- Figure out how to do this for $\mathbb{N}$
- Rearrange the intervals so that they cover of $S$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$

  - This uses the existence of a bijection between $S$ and $\mathbb{N}$
  - Recognize it's fine to make the rearranged intervals overlap; that just decreases the total length of the ensuing set.

Answer (score 3):

Let {$q_n$} be an enumeration of the rationals.
$\cup$ { $B(q_n,1/2^n) \ \ \ \ $ : n in N }
is an open set containing the rationals that has a measure ("length") <= 2 as determined by adding the lengths of all the intervals.